# mysql sync_binlog

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I was told that in mysql synchronization to ensure that everything is being replicated and data is safe, the syn_binlog setting (in my.conf) should be set to 1.

Only this kills performance, what is the best way to solve this?

I also read that this is mostly the cause of ext3 filesystem on linux.
is it safe to set sync_binlog to 0?

Basically the real question is, do you need to turn on sync_binlog if you don't want to lose data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance hit is the cost of the additional seek and writes. sync_binlog = 1 basically tells MySQL how many binary log writes to buffer before flushing the log writes to disk. If it's set to 1, then every write is flushed. 0 tells MySQL to let the filesystem handle it. So, if you have a disk failure you may lose some indeterminate number of binary log writes that are part of the last transaction.

Depending on your storage set up (SAN with battery backed cache, direct attached drives, etc.) a setting of 0 may be safe, or it may not. How much data loss can you and your application tolerate?

to quote the MySQL reference:

> The default value of sync_binlog is 0,
>   which does no synchronizing to disk. A
>   value of 1 is the safest choice
>   because in the event of a crash you
>   lose at most one statement or
>   transaction from the binary log.
>   However, it is also the slowest choice
>   (unless the disk has a battery-backed
>   cache, which makes synchronization
>   very fast).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if we would switch to a battery-backed  raid card, we can safely set sync_binlog to 0?

Comment: That is the theory. Of course, it always depends on the details. We use a pricey SAN with dual battery backed controllers with loads of battery backed cache. We are comfortable with sync_binlog=0 in our situation.

Comment: I think you've got it backwards - if you have a ram/battery backed cache, then writes will be super-fast, so setting it to 1 is your safest choice. However, if you're not writing to ram/battery, then setting to 0 (or >1) saves you some IO time, so you can trade some safety with performance because write are just going into the system write buffer. Setting to >1 says "do a flush every 'n' writes". However, the OS may do a flush on its own before you reach 'n' writes. Setting to 0 says "just leave the OS to do flushes whenever it wants".